# Instagram.get_access_token returns BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, oauth, instagram

I'm trying to authenticate a user with Instagram gem. So I have a page with `code` param returned by instagram, and I only need to send it back with POST request. According to gem documentation I need to do something like:

```
get "/oauth/callback" do
  response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
  session[:access_token] = response.access_token
  redirect "/feed"
end
```

so I have

```
  def authenticate
    response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "http://127.0.0.1:3000")
    session[:access_token] = response.access_token
    redirect "/feed"
  end
```

And I'm getting

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 957ms

Instagram::BadRequest (POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/: 400):
  app/controllers/instagram_controller.rb:25:in `authenticate'
```

I tried making curl request as per Instagram api documentation, and it works with the same params.

About client_id, I store those keys in instagram.rb in initializers, so it looks like

```
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "123345"
  config.client_secret = "123123"
end

CALLBACK_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just in case it's useful, [here's](https://github.com/JamesChevalier/Little-Corner/blob/master/app/controllers/instagram_controller.rb) how I'm implementing Instagram (the `INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN ` it's referring to is set in [environment.rb](https://github.com/JamesChevalier/Little-Corner/blob/master/config/environment.rb#L51) - it's so that if Instagram has been set up already, it can't be re-authenticated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. So, I have devise in my app as well, and I didn't put "redirect_url" in config.omniauth over there. Exactly the same thing people talking about over here https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/22.
Thanks for help.